# Converting variable voltage to constant voltage / variable current

Tags: voltage-regulator, battery-charging, solar-cell

I'm using solar panels + a micro wind turbine to charge a decent sized LiPo battery using this circuit - http://www.adafruit.com/products/390. The problem is that the solar/wind stuff will produce a highly variable voltage (anywhere from 0 to 30V+). To feed the ada module, should I be looking at just a switching regulator, or are there other considerations given the high variability of input voltage and current?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adafruit module looks good but it's only really meant for input voltages below 6V. To maintain efficiency you should use a low drop-out switching buck regulator capable of withstanding the 30Vs you might apply.

I'd recommend the AD8610 (mainly because I've used it on two designs): -

[image]

It's maximum input voltage is 42V so be aware of this. On one design I put a switch-off-when-the-volts-gets-over-35V circuit with a couple of MOSFETs just to protect it.

When you under feed it with voltage it still pretty much acts as a voltage follower be be aware of the under-voltage lock-out it needs to be tied to Vin to get the most out of it.

Comment: Yes, sorry - I meant a regulator in front of the adafruit module..

Comment: Could I use a zener to siphon off anything about 40V or so, rather than just shutting the whole thing down?

Comment: You can use a zener for sure but a better circuit is to use the zener on the base of a transistor with input to collector and output from emitter. It makes a decent voltage regulator but it all depends on load current and there's obviously series power lost in the transistor. There are not many circuits around for this but maybe there's a higher vintage version of the LT  chip.

Answer (score 0):

Yes one can use a rectifier-based DC converter to handle 0 - 30 volts input and rated current. The output voltage will be specified in tech specifications. Also check web for AC to DC or DC to DC step up/down converters as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a dedicated battery charging IC for this so you don't destroy your battery. There are a number available, and without knowing more about your specific setup (# of cells, charging current, etc) the best I can offer is [this list of battery charging ICs](https://www.analog.com/en/products.html#!cols_1032,1033,1067,1806,1068,1069,1112,1367!s_1067,0!gtd_!1033_>30!1806_Li-Polymer). The LTC4000-1 looks like it will do what you want, but requires a number of supporting parts:

[image: LTC4000-1]
<sub>(source: [linear.com](https://cds.linear.com/image/9580.png))</sub>

The LT3650-4.1 has a smaller voltage input range, but looks to be much simpler:

[image: LT3650]
<sub>(source: [linear.com](https://cds.linear.com/image/8295.png))</sub>

Comment: The adafruit circuit *is* a dedicated battery charging IC (+some supporting parts), it just needs voltage that doesn't exceed 6V. My question is how to feed that specific circuit from a power source that can go to 30V or more.

Comment: Ah, I see that you clarified your question as I was answering it. However, replacing the module with one of the ICs linked to above would be just as easy as adding your own regulator in front of the module.